# Is there a specific technique graphic artists use for this illustration?

Tags: vector, graphic-styles, technique, art

I've always wondered if there was a specific method/technique that graphic artists use to create the patterning in this croc?[image]

Comment: Do you have any other examples of the type of pattern you're talking about?

Comment: It looks manually drawn. Is that a digital illustration, are you sure it's vector?

Comment: @Luciano: The image is saved as a JPG, which introduces artefacts, which makes it look manually drawn. If this is originally a digital image, it should not have been saved as JPG (but as PNG), and the artefacts wouldn't have been there.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand jpeg artifacts come from the fact that _this_ image is a jpeg, doesn't prove the original is also raster. Or digital.

Comment: @Luciano: Of course not.

Answer (score 25):

Using Illustrator:

- Make a Pattern Brush using two paths

[image: MODULE]

- Adjust the spacing and choose Tints and Shades method to apply a brush color

[image: Pattern Brush]

- Make some irregular paths with this pattern brush

[image: brush]

- Select them and from menu Object → Expand Appearance
- Apply a Roughen effect to give a handmade appearance

[image: Roughen]

[image]

Comment: Impressive; I thought for sure it was manually drawn.  And it may be, but here's a technique to produce that result more easily!

Comment: The original is obviously not done like this, because all the "scales" are different.

Comment: @OrangeDog See my answer

Answer (score 2):

As a Follow-Up to Danielilo's excellent answer and to reply to OrangeDog's comment.

> The original is obviously not done like this, because all the "scales"
>   are different

---

### You can achieve almost exactly this with a few more steps.

To achieve even more non-uniformity than just roughening them.

Start off by ungrouping all the elements and then you can use Transform Each (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>)

[image]

One more step further you can perform a Transform Each on the individual components (swoop and line) to further control.

### Swoops

[image]

### Lines

[image]

Comment: Pretty cool. But I'm still not convinced the original isn't hand-painted. OP has no evidence that it wasn't.

Comment: @OrangeDog There are enough repeating elements that patterns probably were used. Then hand-drawn elements were added to up the authenticity.